# Data-toggle with Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a href with a ***data-toggle*** and a ***data-target*** in there. ***Onclick is return false***. Its on the end of a table and triggers some stuff.

```
<a href="" onclick="return false;" data-toggle="childrows" data-target="ID"></a>
```

Now i want the same thing when the complete table row is clicked and not only the href. So i got a Jquery function, that triggers when the row is clicked.

```
$("#produkttable tr").click(function() {
                        id = $(this).attr('id');        
                    });
```

Its works so far and I have the table row ID. But now ***I have no clue how to trigger the data-toggle and data-target.*** Im quite new to JQuery and need some help.

Thanks guys

Comment: Can you please provide a more complete picture of your code, include the html table and the complete JQuery function that you are trying to use. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "trigger the data-toggle..."? Attributes aren't 'triggered' in any meaningful sense. Also, this is a good time to a) get away from using inline event handlers (`onclick`) and b) meet jQuery's `.on()` instead of alias methods like `.click()` (though there's nothing wrong with the latter.)

Comment: `id = this.id`; it's faster in operation, easier to read, easier to understand, shorter to write...unless the `id` is being changed at some point and you need to retrieve the original  set-in-the-original-HTML value there's no reason to use jQuery's `attr()` method . And even if you needed the original HTML-set value, `this.getAttribute(id)` is still arguably easier to read, write and understand.

Comment: For anyone's FYI: `data-toggle="childrows"` is (most likely) part of `datatables` which, similar to bootstrap's `data-toggle=` will have some script to pick up this attribute and apply some code to.  Hence "trigger data-toggle" means "trigger the (library) that is applied to that data- attribute"

Comment: @DavidThomas also think you mean "`this.getAttribute(id)` is arguably **harder** to read, write and understand".  Horses for courses.

Comment: @Utkanos: you're absolutely right; edited the comment to correct my phrasing. freedomn-m: no, but I appreciate others might feel differently about it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Can you try something like this? You have a toggle method available in jQuery for these kinds of functionalities

Please See [Jquery Toggle Reference here](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

```
  $("#data-toggle-button-id").click(function(){
        $("#data-target-id").toggle();
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually, `data-attributes` are used to add some private data to an element when they are no more appropriate elements, it's to be abble to add custom attributes and it's not a standard way to trigger some function for me. Maybe take a loot at [the W3C documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp) for this.

For your problem, I think you are using the Bootstrap library, so you can take a look at this part of the [bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/buttons/#toggle-states) to be able to deal with `data-toogle`.

If you want to trigger some custom function when clicking on the last row of you table (I assume that's what you want to do from your question), you can do this (it only use jquery):

```
$("#produkttable tr:last-child").click(function(){
    //here $(this) is your element, so you can directly use it for your need
    callAnOtherFunctionOrDoSomeStuff();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can emulate a click on the anchor (`<a>`) itself with `.click()`:

```
$("a[data-target]", this).click();
```

where `this` is the `tr` and `a[data-target]` is any anchor with a `data-target` attribute.

```
$("#produkttable tr").click(function() {
    $("a[data-target]", this).click();
});
```